# Eclipse add Tomcat 7 blank server name

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I was trying to add Tomcat 7 in my Eclipse in Ubuntu. When I click "Add new server" in Eclipse and select "Tomcat v7.0 Server", the field "Server Name" is blank and I cannot type in anything in that textbox as shown below:

[image: Eclipse Add Tomcat Server]

What I did before is I deleted a Tomcat 7 server from Eclipse and I was trying to reinstall Tomcat 7. But it doesn't allow me to type anything in that textbox and I cannot proceed to the "Next" button. My environment is Ubuntu Linux and Eclipse for JavaEE.

Comment: The same issue happens in Windows 8 too, which can be resolved by deleting files as mentioned

Answer (score 536, accepted):

It is a bug in Eclipse. I had exactly the same problem, also on Ubuntu with Eclipse Java EE Juno.

Here is the workaround that worked for me:

1. Close Eclipse
2. In `{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` delete the following two files:

   - `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`
   - `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs`
3. Restart Eclipse

Source: [eclipse.org Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/453143/)

Comment: This is the fix for Windows, too.

Comment: Good one... Works on Windows 8!

Comment: In my case I had to delete (or even better, rename) org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core.prefs too.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.10 and Eclipse 4.4.1.
But strange, the bug exists in Eclipse for such a long time...

Comment: I did what you said, and I've got this: Cannot publish to the server because it is missing its runtime environment. :(

Comment: This still happens on Eclipse Mars SR2!

Comment: thanks it's still works in ubuntu 16.04 ! and this still happen in eclipse Neon.1a,,

Comment: i can only see projects in workspace directory. there is no other folder with ./metadata. Its not even hidden, i did ls -lrt on the directory. But there are not other directories.

Comment: thanks it solved the issue, this bug is present for Eclipse Neon as well

Comment: Works for Eclipse Neon on MacOS High Sierra with Tomcat 9.0.

Comment: Doing this in win 10 apaprently deletes your Server completely and it cannot be undone by pasting the files back in.

Answer (score 23):

I am running kepler in ubuntu and had the same problem getting eclipse to recognize the tomcat7 server. My path to install directory was fine and deleting/renaming the files only did not fix it either.

This is what worked for me:

run the following in terminal:

```
cd ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/    
rm org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs    
rm org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo service tomcat7 stop
sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 disable
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf conf
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 log
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/tomcat7/conf
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/common common
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/server server
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/shared shared
```

restart eclipse, delete tomcat7 server. Re-add server and everything then worked.

Here is the link I used.
http://linux.mjnet.eu/post/1319/tomcat-7-ubuntu-13-04-and-eclipse-kepler-problem-to-run/

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue except the "Server Name" field was *disabled*.

Found this was due to the Apache Tomcat v7.0 runtime environment pointing to the wrong folder. This was fixed by going to Window - Preferences - Server - Runtime Environments, clicking on the runtime environment entry and clicking "Edit..." and then modifying the Tomcat installation directory.

Answer (score 8):

**I had same issue before: the server name was not appearing in server while configuring with eclipse**

**I tried all the solutions which are provided over here, but they didn't work for me.**

> I resolved it, by simply following these simple tips
>
> Step1: Windows --> Preferences --> Server --> Run time Environments
>   --> Add --> select the tomcat version which was unavailable before --> next --> browse the location of your server with same version
>
> Step2: go to servers and select your server version --> next -->
>   Finish
>
> Issue resolved!!! :)

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue, and I changed the workspace to new location, and it worked.
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

so weird but this worked for me.

1. close eclipse
2. start eclipse as `eclipse --clean`

Answer (score 2):

After trying **@Philipp Claßen** steps, even if did not work then,

**Change eclipse, workspace and tomcat directory.** [tested only for Windows7]

I know somebody might say that is not correct, 
but that did work for me after @Phillipp's steps not worked for me.

It took me 4 hours to find this brute force method solution.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem today, and deleting files `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs` and `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` didn't work.

Finally I found it's permission issue:

By default `<apache-tomcat-version>/conf/*` can be read only by owner, after I made it readable for all, it works! So run this command:

```
chmod a+r <apache-tomcat-version>/conf/*
```

Here is the link where I found the root cause:

http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/eclipse-cannot-create-tomcat-server.953960/#post-5058434

Comment: It seems to be the origin of the problem I faced: some versions of Tomcat don't provide read right on conf files to all users, Eclipse is unable to init the configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the tomcat directory was owned by root, and I was not running eclipse as root.

So I had to

```
sudo chown -R  $USER apache-tomcat-VERSION/
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to create a new workspace in eclipse/STS.

```
File -> Switch Workspace -> Others...
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting/Moving files org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs and org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on Ubuntu 17.04 with Tomcat 8.0 the problem persists. What helped me was the combination of deleting the prefs files:

```
rm ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs    
rm ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
```

and linking to `catalina.policy` (somewhat differently than how @michael-brooks suggested for his configuration):

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat8/policy/catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
```