# eclipse can't create tomcat8 server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 15.10 on my computer and I have installed eclipse mars. I would like to create a web project but I can't load the server.

I have installed both tomcat 7 and 8 but if I go on Server Tab and click on Create new Server, [I have this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqcc5.png) it doesn't allow me neither to insert a server name nor click on finish.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in bugzilla.eclipse.org today:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489194

(For me it works with Tomcat 7 - but I would like to use Tomcat 8 :-) )

And I found a workaround:
[Eclipse - Add Server - Next Button is disabled when I select a specific Tomcat (e.g tomcat8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679099/eclipse-add-server-next-button-is-disabled-when-i-select-a-specific-tomcat)