# How do I get rid of the below stated issue when I try to add tomcat to Spring Tool suite in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to add Tomcat server in to STS but I do am not able to do it. Some times the server name doesn't appear when I try to add Tomcat by selecting it from the list, I can't type in the server name myself as well and If that step works properly (I mean when the serve name appears automatically which it should when server is selected form the list); the Finished button is grayed out in the resource page which is the last step in adding the Tomcat server to STS.

Comment: why you are not using pivotal tc server for development?

Comment: I have never used it till date; and I am comfortable using Tomcat. Even If I want to learn how to use Pivotal and use it, I still would want to solve the issue I have now.

Comment: do u provided path of Tocat Installation Directory?

Comment: Yes I have provided the path to tomcat directory and also changed the permission of the directory to RWD, still it did not work. I ended up getting the same error. For a fresh copy of STS when I try to add tomcat the finished button is grayed out at the resource step which is the last step, and when I try the next time the server name text box is empty and I am not able to enter the name manually as well; and with out the name I can't proceed to further steps.

Comment: Can you also share some screenshots?

Comment: Think you are changing the "server's host name" (the 1st text box) which should be left as "localhost" since the server is to be run locally (right?). Anything different from localhost makes "Finish" button disabled. Changing "Server's Name" value works fine and Finish button is enabled

Comment: I am not changing anything. I am using all default.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Eclipse
- In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings delete the following two files:
- org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
- org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
- Restart Eclipse

this is actually a bug.
got this from this question actually [Eclipse add Tomcat 7 blank server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name)