# Unable to add tomcat 8 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

http://imageshack.com/a/img907/1062/PdSLWN.png[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm3hq.png)

I am trying to add tomcat 8 in my eclipse. But unable to add the same. When I click on the apache tomcat 8 the "Server name" tab is disable.But in the case of 7 its enable. Please suggest me to solve this or give some good tutorials for reconfigure the same.

Comment: Follow this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an old bug within eclipse. The question was already answered here:
[Eclipse add Tomcat 7 blank server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name)

Comment: thanks a lot.I am new in tomcat